# Google analytics experiments sub-domain tracking

Tags: google-analytics, subdomain, google-experiments

Is there something special about tracking a google analytics experiment across subdomains?

I have an experiment set up in an account which tracks a top-level domain and several sub-domains. The experiment is implemented in javascript and the experiment Id and variation are set using

```
cxApi.setChosenVariation(chosenVariation, opt_experimentId)
```

which is placed above tracking code (included via google tag manager). When creating the experiment I gave two dummy urls as the page variations and chose the 'Insert code manually' option, (although I did not insert the code as advised at https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/experiments-client-side :"The Experiment ID is the only information needed to continue and implement the experiment. The JavaScript snippet is not used.").

The experiment tracking is working for the top-level-domain, but not any of the subdomains. This seems strange because the account in which this is set up records all other tracking data successfully for all sub-domains. Does anyone have any idea what I might need to do to get the experiment tracking working in the sub-domains as well?

Thanks

Comment: Got the same issue. Any idea?